# Пользовательский литерал с заглавной буквы

Tags: c++

На [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) сказано, что следующий код выдаёт ошибку (пример в конце раздела literal operators), однако у меня в gcc всё компилируется без каких-либо сообщений. Почему?

```
double operator"" _Z(long double) {
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: msvc тоже компилирует оба варианта, возможно cppreference устарел

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Идентификаторы, начинающиеся с подчеркивания и заглавное буквы являются зарезервированными для реализации. Но само по себе их использование не обязательно является ошибкой. Для пользовательских литералов действительно есть исключение, позволяющее использовать иначе зарезервированные идентификаторы при слитном написании. Такой случай приводится в стандарте в качестве примера:

> **16.5.8 User-defined literals [over.literal]**
>   **8.**
>   `double operator""_Bq(long double);` // OK: does not use the reserved identifier _Bq (5.10)
>   `double operator"" _Bq(long double);` // uses the reserved identifier _Bq (5.10)

Более конкретный пример того, чем это чревато. В VC++ имеются SAL аннотации, использующие макросы с зарезервированными идентификаторами, например `_In_`

```
#include <sal.h>

double operator""_In_(long double) { // гарантировано работает
    return 0;
}

double operator"" _In_(long double) { // ошибка в vc++ или clang (c SAL) но работает в gcc
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Обязан ли компилятор выдавать ошибку/предупреждение для второго примера по стандарту?

Comment: @serafim Не обязан, собственно их использование не обязательно является ошибкой. Однако поведение и работоспособность такого кода могут менять в зависимости от особенностей реализации.

Answer (score 3):

Пример на cppreference просто хочет сказать, что имена вроде `_Z` являются зарезервированными. То есть ошибка в том примере та же, что и, например, в объявлении

```
int _Z;
```

Однако нет ничего удивительного в том, что компиляторы не диагностируют такие нарушения. Имена эти зарезервированы для использования реализацией, однако когда компилятор получает уже "собранную" единицу трансляции на вход, в ней уже бывает трудно или невозможно отличить, какой код является пользовательским, а какой принадлежит реализации. Поэтому компилятору трудно понять, является ли каждое использование зарезервированного имени нарушением.

Comment: Стандарт разрешает компиляторам не диагностировать такое?

Comment: Standard раздел 5.10 Identifiers "Each identifier that contains a double underscore __ or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter is reserved to the implementation for any use."

Comment: @goldstar_labs в это я верю, а про диагностику что сказано? Обязаны ли компиляторы выдавать ошибку/предупреждение или могут не выдавать?

Comment: @serafim, такой информации не нашел

Comment: @serafim, обязывать компиляторы выдавать на это предупреждение нет никакого смысла, потому что весь смысл этого запрета является вынужденным. Т.е. подобные имена зарезервированы для разработчиков «кишков» стандартной библиотеки, а при совпадении имён получаются все прелести неопределённого поведения. Т.е. это запрет не жёсткий, но жестокий. Контролировать никто не станет, но если соблюдать не будете, то рискуете нарваться на интересные последствия. На неопределённое поведение вообще диагностики стандартом не «вешаются». Насколько я помню, исключений нет.